Tableau-API-Lib in Python is not working when I'm trying to host in AWS Lambda
I’m working on automating a monthly task using Tableau-API-Lib in Python within an AWS Lambda function with scheduled triggers. However, I'm encountering issues getting Tableau-API-Lib to function correctly in the Lambda environment.
I’ve tried packaging Tableau-API-Lib as a zip file and adding it as a Layer in AWS Lambda, but that didn’t work. I also placed Tableau-API-Lib in the root directory alongside lambda_function.py, but that approach also failed.
I’ve exhausted the solutions available in AWS Lambda documentation and online resources without success.
Could you suggest alternative approaches or potential workarounds for achieving this automation?
Please see the attached screenshot of the error for reference.

Please update your question to add a minimum example of code and the error message as text not an image. So others may reproduce the error/ easily copy paste.

We run it as an AWS Glue job. Is that an option for your architecture?
